# Does combining queries affect SEO?

Tags: google, seo

In my website instead of using individual queries for each request, I combined them like the following in one query:

www.mysite.com/search/?q=c1|~|c3|~

I just divide it after page loads and if you look at the link I use "~" instead of empty queries.
My question is, "Does this kind of work affect SEO?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google recommends that you prevent the crawl of ["of search results pages or other auto-generated pages that don't add much value"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#2). Matt Cutts (head of Google Webspam) has also [repeatedly echoed this](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3100230).

So, my answer would be, yes, having indexable searches is negatively affecting your SEO, but not because you add multiple terms.

However on the flip side of the coin, the first few results for [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=blue%20cardigan&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) are all search results, using a search style like yours.